# Why does cassandra return only a single row when I select in the opposite order of my clustering?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0

I've got a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "DeviceCounterMonth" (
  "counterGuid" uuid,
  "deviceGuid" uuid,
  "sampleTimeLocal" text,
  ...
  "tenantGuid" uuid
  PRIMARY KEY (("counterGuid", "deviceGuid"), "sampleTimeLocal")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("sampleTimeLocal" DESC)
...
```

When I run the following query, I get lots of rows back, as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM "DeviceCounterMonth"
WHERE "counterGuid" = b9dea20a-83a7-45d9-9ed9-6c502fee15b1
  AND "deviceGuid" = 804a0387-221a-44c0-abae-d93745bd15cc
ORDER BY "sampleTimeLocal" DESC;
```

However, If I change `DESC` to `ASC`, I only get back a single row. In that row, `sampleTimeLocal` is `null`, which is not true of any of the rows returned by the first query. What's going on here?

**Update**: If instead of `*`, I select all columns except `tenantGuid`, it returns the correct result.

Comment: It does looks like a bug. Do you use secondary indexes? Which version of Cassandra do you use?

Comment: cqlsh 4.1.1, Cassandra 2.0.8, CQL spec 3.1.1, Thrift protocol 19.39.0

Comment: do you use secondary indexes?

Comment: Nope, no secondary indexes

Comment: I would recommend to file an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Comment: I will as soon as I can come up with a minimal repro (which is proving harder than I thought). I just added an update: leaving off one of the columns causes it to work.

Comment: filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7800